# FFmpeg creates an ouput file shorter than it's longest stream

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Assuming `pipe:0` is a 3 seconds wav file
Assuming `input2.mp4` is a 1 second mp4 file

With this command:

```
ffmpeg -f f32le -ar 44100 -channels 2 -i pipe:0 -t 5 -itsoffset 4 -i input2.mp4 -y -f mp4 -c:v copy -map 0:a -map 1:v output.mp4
```

I would expect that `output.mp4` has a duration of 5 seconds, because the longest stream, the video stream, lasts that long.

However, the output file only lasts 3 seconds, the duration of the audio stream. If I play `output.mp4` in QuickTime, there is indeed only 3 seconds of audio only.

Interestingly, when I analyse the output with `ffprobe`, I can see that the video stream has a 5 seconds duration and a 4 second start time, as it should.

How can I make the output as long as it's longest stream? I'm pretty sure I could re-encode the video stream (instead of copying it), but I want to avoid that. I just don't see why it wouldn't be possible without re-encoding.

Why doesn't `ffmpeg` take in account that there are timestamps going further than 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg will not prolong a particular stream based on the duration of other streams. If you want to extend a stream, use filters - apad for audio and tpad for video. Then add -shortest or a -t duration to limit the output.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to prolong the audio stream based on the duration of the video stream. I just want the final container to have the duration of it's longest stream. Also, why is the container based on the duration of the audio stream instead of the video stream? Are there rules that indicate which type of stream has priority when it comes to setting the duration of a container?

Comment: For streams with offset timestamps, ffmpeg will generate those offsets in the MP4 output using edit lists. If you want to force ffmpeg to store absolute timestamps, add `-use_editlist 0`. for the MP4 output.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, that worked. Where do you even find this option in the documentation? Even a google search with the term "use_editlist" isn't useful. ffmpeg is a great tool, but it has very poor documentation for less used features...

Comment: However, the start_time is now always at 0 when checking with `ffprobe`. What a mess lol

Comment: What's the mess? The audio starts at 0.

Comment: I was referring to the video stream. The video stream should have an offset of 4 (which is listed as start_time with ffprobe), but when `-use_editlist 0` is specified, suddenly it becomes 0.

Comment: That's because without edit lists, the first frame starts at 0 but has a duration of 4+(1/fps) seconds.

Comment: I see. And is there a way to have the first frame start at 4, using the edit list?

Comment: Yes, but with edit list, media timeline starts at 0 and presentation timestamps are offset by the edit list, so file duration will be 3s.

Comment: So, if I understand, there is no way to have the "-use_editlist 0" option (which forces ffmpeg to use absolute timestamps, allowing the container to take the size of the longest stream) and have the correct start_time on the video stream (if the video stream has an offset of 4, the start_time of this stream should be 4) and also have the correct duration for the container (the correct duration of the container would be the duration of it's longest stream). Maybe I'm unaware of many of the complexities of ffmpeg, but it seems to me that it should be easy to do such a simple thing.

Comment: It's a container limitation, not ffmpeg.

Comment: Got it. Are you aware of any other ways that can check the offset of the video stream with ffprobe (when using `-use_editlist 0`)? `start_time` is always set to 0, but there might be another attribute I can look at, or some sort of calculation based on a couple attributes. Or how can I gather information on the first frame that will let me calculate the offset (`4+(1/fps)`)?

Comment: This command seems to do the job: `ffprobe -of json -select_streams v -show_frames -read_intervals %+#1 input.mp4`. Although, if you know of a `ffprobe` command that would deduce the start_time from the whole video stream rather than only the first frame of the video stream, that would be better.